# Redirect a domain on a home network

Tags: redirection

Is it possible to redirect a domain on a home network? Ie. If example.com currently points to 123.123.123.123, is it possible to have it point to 12.12.12.12? I do not own the domain I need redirected, and the redirection would only be for people connected to my network via WiFi. If this is not possible, can I null route the domain? Thanks.

I need this to be done because I want to block certain sites on my home network while simulating that the site is down. I do realize the router has a block function, but it redirects you to a page where it says the site example.com has been blocked etc.

Comment: If you have networking hardware (router/switch) which supports static routing that is an option. Otherwise, if you have a way to force send a 'hosts' file to the devices on your network you could configure that.

Comment: @Abraxas My router supports static routing, how would I do this though? Any links?

Comment: It turns out this doesn't do what I thought it would but it might still be viable. Set your destination IP as the site IPs you want to block. Set a subnet of 255.255.255.255 if it's a specific address. For the 'gateway' IP type in a local IP (possibly one that doesn't exist or of a webserver you run). This should prevent traffic from reaching those sites and should throw an error that the page was not found.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. Your Internet Gateway Device most likely also hosts a DNS “proxy” of sorts. A popular example of this is [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html). It also provides the functionality you want, like this:

```
address=/example.com/12.12.12.12
```

However, there are two main obstacles:

- Your router may run a different program
- You won’t be able to access (let alone modify) the settings

If your router is compatible and you understand what you’re doing(!), you could try [OpenWrt](https://openwrt.org/), an open-source replacement router OS based on Linux. It runs dnsmasq and doesn’t keep you from modifying just about any setting.

Answer (score 0):

No, not with most home routers.

You can however, potentially install third-party firmware that can do this (e.g. DD-WRT, Tomato, etc.)  You could also run your own DNS server on a PC, and have your router use that instead of your ISP, but this is somewhat outside of the realm of home computing.  And lastly, you could modify the individual computers on the network to do this (e.g. edit the Windows host file).